# How do you solve a differential queation with derivatives inside a square on the denominator?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following first order ODE:

$$C = f(x)\frac{y'}{\sqrt{1 + y'^2}}$$

Where $f(x)$ is some function in $x$ and $C$ is a constant.

I am having a miserable time. I tried separation of variables but I end up getting a complex expression and that makes no sense:

\begin{align*}
 &C\sqrt{1 + y'^2} = f(x)y' \\ 
 \iff &C^2(1 + y'^2) = f^2(x)y'^2\\
 \iff &B + By'^2 = f^2(x)y'^2 \\
 \iff &B + By'^2 - f^2(x)y'^2 = 0 \\
 \iff &y'^2( B - f^2(x)) = -B \\
 \iff &y'^2 = \frac{-B}{B - f^2(x)} \\
 \iff &y' = \sqrt{\frac{-B}{B - f^2(x)}} \\
 \iff &dy = \sqrt{\frac{-B}{B - f^2(x)}} dx\\
\end{align*}

With $B = C^2$

Answer (score 2):

You can derive from the original equation that $|f(x)|>|C|$ and that the sign of $y'$ is the product of the signs of $f(x)$ and $C$. This allows you to determine the sign in the explicit equation for $y'$ per
$$
y'(x)={\rm sign}(f(x))\frac{C}{\sqrt{f(x)^2-C^2}}.
$$
This now is a quadrature problem, if that is solvable in symbolic expressions depends on the nature of $f$.

Comment: What if $f(x) = e^x$ for example?

Comment: Then you get to integrate $\int \frac{Ce^{-x}}{\sqrt{1-(Ce^{-x})^2}}dx$, which is a well-known integral after substitution.